# Angular project shows white page after production

Tags: java, css, angularjs, angular, single-page-application

I'm having a problem which I really hope someone here could fix...
I've created an angular project and once I build if for production using ng build --prod , When I try to access the project with a server I only get white page, no console errors. somehow <>app-root> <>app-root/>
 stays hidden. If I add any test text to the page's body it does displayed... I will add some pictures and code to be more clear:

OUTPUT for ng serve:
[output for ng serve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT3sC.jpg)

OUTPUT for after running the app on a server:
[output for running server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWXxF.jpg)

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testapp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="../resources/css/styles.34c57ab7888ec1573f9c.css" th:href="@{/css/styles.34c57ab7888ec1573f9c.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.34c57ab7888ec1573f9c.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.d6e524e11d43dad9c75a.js"></script></body>
   -->
</head>
<body>
<h1>BEFORE APP ROOT</h1>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="../resources/js/runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="../resources/js/polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="../resources/js/main.d6e524e11d43dad9c75a.js"></script>
  <h1>AFTER APP ROOT</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

what could cause this? please comment if you need to to post any other code/pictures.. I'm really stuck with that issue

thanks by heart

**UPDATE: I updated pictures and code for a new Angular project to avoid confusions

Update: [update3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyf39.jpg)another screenshoot after changing base href to

```
 <base href="/testapp/">
```

AND a picture of my spring project[in eclipse]: 
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze8St.jpg)

Comment: Mh, I had a similar issue, try changing the base href like this > `<base href="./">`

Answer (score 1):

That's because the base href is wrong:

```
<base href="/">
```

This must reflect the same URL you use to access the angular application.

Change it to

```
<base href="/couponsystem/">
```

Comment: @BlackSlash yes I do get errors this time: localhost/:31 GET http://localhost:8080/couponsystem/runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js 404 ()
localhost/:17 GET http://localhost:8080/couponsystem/styles.059cd1bb0b630b8e092d.css 404 ()
2localhost/:31 GET http://localhost:8080/couponsystem/polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js 404 ()

Comment: I think I better make new empty angular project just to test this issue

Comment: @hindi1991 Then it's working, changing the base href solved the issue. Now the browser can't find those files, so you have to place them in the right directory and you'll see your application up and running!

Comment: @BlackSlash I already had this issue with paths before I already fixed that... the js files are running

Comment: @hindi1991 It's impossible. If you have an error 404 on those file, they are not found and can't be running. The browser doesn't run files it can't load.

Comment: I know that. adding /couponsystem/ makes the error, what i mean is that i fixed that resource not found error earlier

Comment: @hindi1991 Then unfix that. The base href should be the one I told you, that's how angular works. If you moved its files, move them back where they were before you "fixed" it. Or, do a fresh build and just change the base href to the one I wrote.

Comment: but in order to access the angular app I dont use any URL, but localhost:4200. I created a new app just so we don't confuse with all the coupon stuff, i will update the post in a sec.

Comment: @hindi1991 Yes, that's why the base href here must be `/`. Based on your screenshot you put your application under `/couponsystem/`, so the base href must be updated accordingly.

Comment: hey I just updated the pics could you have a look now? thanks :) @BackSlash

Comment: @hindi1991 I saw the updated screenshots. As I already told you, within the development server the base href must be /, but you need to change that accordingly when you build for production. Your app on the :8080 server is under /couponsystem/, so that should be your base href after the build.

Comment: ok I did so now but i still see white page..... I add another screenshoot in the post, i fixed the paths and no console errors

Comment: @hindi1991 does your testapp do something? If it's just a blank app, it's behaving correctly.

Comment: well you should see angular's default wellcome page right? just like when you do ng-serve

Comment: @hindi1991 Look, I tried to reproduce the same steps on my pc, here's what I did. 1) Opened a cmd window on C:\ 2) created a folder named "angular", 3) `ng new testapp` 4) `cd testapp` 5) `ng serve` -> [this is what came out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCKmY.png). Then: 1) `ng build --prod` 2) opened `dist/index.html` 3) changed `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/testapp/">` and published `dist` under `localhost:8080/testapp` as you did -> [this is what came out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlwsQ.png). Reproduce my steps and it will work. If your app doesn't work, the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply this in your index.html and it will work like a charm

```
<base href="#">
```